# Testcontainers Quickstart Example does not work?

Tags: java, testcontainers

I'm trying the Junit 5 Testcontainers Quickstart Example:

https://www.testcontainers.org/quickstart/junit_5_quickstart/

I use version 5.6.1 for jupiter and version 1.14.3 for testcontainers.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

```
import org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

@Testcontainers
public class TestcontainersDemo {
    @Container
    public GenericContainer redis = new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("redis:5.0.3-alpine"))
            .withExposedPorts(6379);

}
```

Eclipse IDE is complaining

```
The method parse(String) is undefined for the type DockerImageName
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which version of testcontainers are you using?

Comment: Edited! I use the testcontainers version from the manual but a higher jupiter version (5.6.1 instead of 5.4.2)

Comment: I think the problem is that the example is already updated for the 1.15 release candidate, while the `DockerImageName.parse(...)` isn't yet available in the published 1.14.3 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testcontainer `1.14.3` just use.

```
@Container
public GenericContainer<?> redis = new GenericContainer<>("redis:5.0.3-alpine")
.withExposedPorts(6379);
```

Or switch to the release candidate, e.g. version `1.15.0-rc2`, which supports

```
DockerImageName.parse("redis:5.0.3-alpine")
```